# Present tense passive (The moon is made of the same material as earth.)

Tags: adjectives, present-tense, past-participles

> The moon is made of the same material as earth.

I got this sentence from a grammar book as an example of **present tense**. However, the past participle **made** is confusing to me. Is this also an example of passive voice? Or **made of the same material as earth** is a participial adjective phrase?

Comment: That is a sentence in the passive form: I'm making a cake. The cake **is made of** chocolate, flour, sugar and butter.

Answer (score 1):

- I make a cake on Saturdays. [regular voice, action verb]
- The cakes are made of flour, sugar, butter and eggs.

Passive voice: to be made of

- The moon is not made of cheese.
- The universe made the moon.

Answer (score 0):

The tensed verb is **is**.  That's what makes it a present-tense construction.

Many grammarians would not apply the label "passive voice" to a construction like this one, inasmuch as there is no reference to the agent; they would understand the past participle of transitive verb "make", **made**,  to be a predicate adjective or subject complement.

X is made of {some ingredients or material}.

But the underlying notion of transitivity implies that the earth did not make itself; rather, it achieved its state of being "made" by way of some force or forces external to it. That state was conferred upon it.

The same is true of a cake.

> A cake is made of flour, water, sugar, and flavorings.

A baker made it, of course; it did not spring into existence. But in this construction the maker is absent from the picture, and the focus is on the *composition* of the cake.

We often encounter constructions like this:

> Our cakes are made by loving hands using only the finest ingredients.
>
> Our cakes are made using only the finest ingredients.

The boundaries are not clear-cut, but the first seems more like a passive to me.

> Loving hands make our cakes using only the finest ingredients.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please let me know how the sentence can be dissected? _The moon_ is the subject. _is_ is a linking verb. But what is the function of _made of_ and _the same material as earth_ (sorry it's not clear to me)?

Comment: I would parse it as follows: **made** together with its complement, the prepositional phrase "of the same material as earth",  is predicated of the subject **moon** as an attribute.   Compare: *The wooden shed is painted with an oil-based paint.*   The past participles of the transitive verbs (make, paint) are adjectival here, and these verbs (and their past participles) can be complemented by a prepositional phrase that qualifies the action that results in the subject's acquisition of the attribute.

Comment: Personally, I think the adjective/verb thing is an unresolved academic issue. The wooden shed is painted (very year) with an oil-based paint. Not an issue I would argue about here.